# Export Product Catalog to CSV (Magento 2.1.6)

Tags: magento2, export

I'm pretty new to Magento 2 and I'm looking for getting a product catalogue export in CSV with some attributes that are not included in the built-in export functionality of Magento (such as product ID).

I have a code I wrote for Magento 1.9 which worked perfectly and I know that catalogue and product classes in Magento 2 are totally different.

In the code I have for M1, I used the following pieces in order to retrieve the store's catalogue and products;

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
.
.
.
.
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); //Retreive the catalogue
foreach ($products as $product) { //loop through the products in the catalogue
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId()); //get product details according to the product ID
.
.
.
.
?>
```

I've searched on Google for several hours in order to look for the changes that I should make in order to access the catalogue and products in M2 but haven't found any proper answer.

May anyone please explain to me how can I access this information in M2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

use the below code to getting product collection

```
  <?php
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection 
$productCollection */

   $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

 /** Apply filters here */

 $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

  foreach ($collection as $product){
   echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
  }  

 ?>
```